# Project Tango Development Environment (java) problems

Tags: java, android, google-project-tango

I am running into a problem when trying to build/run Project Tango sample programs provided on Google's Project Tango Developer website. Specifically my problem relates to the Quickstart Java provided in the Project Tango SDK API.  Here's where I've gotten to so far:
1) Have Tango Tablet with adb debug properly set up and verified (adb devices)
2) I have cloned the Quickstart Java project onto my machine (as well as the entire  tango-examples-java directory.
3)I am using Android Studio as my IDE

From this point, once I try to run Quickstart Java I am getting build errors and cannot test Quickstart Java as the project will not build.  Is this something that is related to build.gradle files or some other configuration I am not aware of?? I am stuck!!

Comment: can you post the log of build errors you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

Brian Griffey posted to the G+ page last night about his branch of the Java sources he has building with Android Studio [here](https://plus.google.com/106493304015091401117/posts/bEmtCM34743)